# How do I tell what battery my laptop needs if I don't currently have a battery installed?

Tags: laptop, battery

First, a little backstory:

A few months ago the monitor for my Acer Aspire F5-573 laptop shattered, so I took it to get fixed. Ever since then, the computer has said "no battery detected". I finally got fed up with its inability to operate without a power chord, so I looked up how to fix it. I followed all the instructions, up to where it said "take out the battery". I was alarmed to find that there was no battery installed, so my conclusion was that during the repair of my laptop, the battery was removed, and someone forgot to replace it.

Anyway, the store is no longer in business (conveniently), so I need to buy a new battery myself. All the instructions online for identifying what type of battery to buy tell you to look at the labels on your current one, but as you can probably guess, I'm not able to do that without actually having a battery to look at. Is there any way to tell what type of battery I need to buy without looking at the current one?

Comment: What is the exact model number of your laptop. No one here can guess without that.

Comment: @John It's an Acer Aspire F5-573 x64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Using a web search for **Acer Aspire F5-573**, I found accurate results for the battery in your machine. Here is the battery I found:

Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer Aspire *F5-573* 14.6 Volt Li-ion Laptop Battery (2200mAh / 32Wh)

https://www.battdepot.com/ca/search/model/acer/Aspire+F5-573.aspx?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlcb89Nmq6QIVFeDICh1sjQD1EAAYASAAEgJwIfD_BwE

Also look at slightly different model number:

Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer Aspire **V5-573**-54208G75aii 15 Volt Li-Polymer Laptop Battery (3000mAh / 45Wh).

https://www.battdepot.com/ca/model/notebook+battery/acer/aspire+v5-573-54208g75aii/lac232.aspx

The "F" battery is smaller than the "V" battery.

Comment: That can't be right, because the battery slot in my laptop is large and empty, and that one is very skinny.

Comment: Are you very certain we have the exact model as the battery above is for that model .  There is another battery from the same place:  Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer Aspire V5-573-54208G75aii 15 Volt Li-Polymer Laptop Battery (3000mAh / 45Wh).  The model number is a bit different but take a look:   https://www.battdepot.com/ca/model/notebook+battery/acer/aspire+v5-573-54208g75aii/lac232.aspx

Comment: No, it's with an F alright. Is it possible that the big empty space is for something else? There's a spot for plugging something in, similar to the chord attached to the battery.

Comment: That could be. You have pictures of both so you can compare and see. All the "F" batteries are the same relative size. Only the "V" battery was noticeably bigger.

Comment: In order to make this answer more complete and useful to visitors with a similar problem it would be good to demonstrate *how* to find out what battery to get.

Answer (score 0):

> All the instructions online for identifying what type of battery to
>   buy tell you to look at the labels on your current one, but as you can
>   probably guess, I'm not able to do that without actually having a
>   battery to look at. Is there any way to tell what type of battery I
>   need to buy without looking at the current one?

Yes, there is. There are **specialised shops for laptop batteries**, most of which have online shops. These shops usually let you enter your laptop model, and then tell you the type of battery you need. It's in these shops best interest that you find the right battery for your laptop (so you buy it), so they tend to have information for a fairly large list of models. If one shop does not have your model, just try a different one.

Alternatively, you can got to the **laptop manufacturer site**. They usually have a "Maintenance manual" or "replacement part list" or similar for each model, and sometimes even an online shop for spare parts. That should also tell you what battery you need. Also, make sure the shop guarantees that the battery is the right one for your laptop before you order - then (in most jurisdictions) you are entitled to return it and get a refund if it is not.

For example, the official product support page for the Acer Aspire F5-537 is this: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6738?b=1
There, under "Product Details" you can enter your laptop's serial number to get the exact specifications (and hopefully the battery you need).

**Caveat:** Make sure you get the laptop model number *exactly* right. Laptops (like many electronics) are notorious for having very simliar model designations with radically different hardware. So the (invented) models "Compute Advance 337X" and "Compute Advance 337XD" may need different batteries. Ideally, try to find the "model code", "model designation code" or similar which many manufacturers have, and loop up that one.